# Learning Ruby, Looking for Possible Refactoring for If Statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I've got a few ideas but wanted to get a few other options. Here is the ugly:

```
def normal_balance
  if type.to_s == 'Asset' or type.to_s == 'Expense'
    if contra
      "Credit"
    else
      "Debit"
    end
  else
    if contra
      "Debit"
    else
      "Credit"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What type of value is `type`? (Why are you calling `to_s` on it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%w[Asset Expense].include?(type.to_s) == !!contra ? "Credit" : "Debit"
```

The `!!` is just there to force `contra` into a boolean, so we can compare it using `==`. It could also be written as

```
%w[Asset Expense].include?(type.to_s) ^ contra ? "Debit" : "Credit"
```

But that's less readable, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks.  Certainly most concise.  Took some reading to refresh my self on a few of the operators.

Comment: Isn't `^` going to return the opposite of `==`? It's XOR, so `true ^ true == false` whereas `(true == true) == true`. Perhaps you meant `&`?

Comment: @Andrew: That's why I swapped the strings. Boolean `a ^ b` is equivalent to `!!a != !!b`. `&` has different semantics, by the way.

Comment: @NiklasB. Ahhhh did not see that, my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly a ruby-specific method, but since you're just inverting a boolean if a value in a given set, you can represent the boolean as a variable and then just use one condition to obtainin the 'debit' or 'credit' string.

```
def normal_balance
  debit = %w[Asset Expense].include?(type.to_s) ? !contra : contra
  debit ? "Debit" : "Credit"
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Big thing I've taken away here is the ? operator.  I remember reading about it but application didn't come to mind.

Comment: Yeah, it is a discriminator due to the model using datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
def normal_balance(type,con)
  contra = {:yes => 'Debit'}
  contra.default= 'Credit'
  card_type = {:Asset => contra, :Expense => contra}
  card_type.default = contra

  card_type[type.to_sym][con.to_sym]
end
```

This is mostly used for replacing `if` that you use a hash.

I don't know what is the possible value for `contra` so you should replace that in the first hash.

Actually in your case you only test for contra_type. Maybe you should test that only.

Comment: Thanks.  I see that now on the original IF statement